# Multiple Promise.all - wait for each (and all) to finish

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, es6-promise

I am trying to execute multiple `Promise.all()` in sequence and wait for each `Promise.all()` to finish before proceeding and then return `Promise.resolve()`.

In essence I want to

1. first - write data to a temporary location.
2. wait for temporary write to finish then - move the data into place
3. wait for data to be moved into place then - clean up temporary data
4. ***wait for all of above to finish before resolving***

My code lives in a Firebase Realtime database trigger event.

The problem I am experiencing is that the database function finishes too early, before all promises are resolved. Why does the function finish before ALL promises are completed?

```
  return Promise.all(firstPromises)
  .then((firstResult) => {
    // Proceed move data from firstPromises to another location
    let movePromises = []
    movePromises = movePromises.concat(myFunc.moveStuff({dbRoot, from:`${tmpPath}/1`, to:'one'}))
    movePromises = movePromises.concat(myFunc.moveStuff({dbRoot, from:`${tmpPath}/2`, to:'two'}))
    movePromises = movePromises.concat(myFunc.moveStuff({dbRoot, from:`${tmpPath}/3`, to:'three'}))
    movePromises = movePromises.concat(myFunc.moveStuff({dbRoot, from:`${tmpPath}/4`, to:'four'}))
    return Promise.all(movePromises)
  }) 
  .then((moveResult) => {
    // Result from Promise.all(movePromises)
    // Clean up
    return Promise.all(cleanPromises)
  })
  .then((cleanResult) => {
    // Result from Promise.all(cleanPromises)
    return Promise.resolve(true)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error('Error', err)
    // Clean up
    cleanPromises.push(myFunc.cleanup({dbRoot, path:tmpPath}))
    return Promise.all(cleanPromises)
    // return Promise.reject(err)
  })
```

myFunc.moveStuff():

```
moveStuff : ({dbRoot, from, to}) => {
  console.log(`moveStuff from '${from}' --> '${to}'`)
  let myPromises = []
  dbRoot.child(from).once('value', (snaps)=>{
    console.log(`${from} to move:`, snaps.numChildren())
    snaps.forEach((node)=>{
      const path = `${to}/${node.key}`
      const nodeData = node.val()
      myPromises.push(
        dbRoot.child(path).set(nodeData)
        .then((writeRes)=> {
          return dbRoot.child(from).remove()
        })
        .then((deleteRes)=>{
          return Promise.resolve(true)
        })
        .catch((e)=>{
          console.error('moveStuff error', e)
          return Promise.reject(e)
        })
      )
    })
  })
  return myPromises
}
```

This is my console logout:

```
cleanup my/SYSTEM
moveStuff from '/my-tmp/SYSTEM/1' --> 'one'
moveStuff from '/my-tmp/SYSTEM/2' --> 'two'
moveStuff from '/my-tmp/SYSTEM/3' --> 'three'
moveStuff from '/my-tmp/SYSTEM/4' --> 'four'
Function execution took 3473 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
/my-tmp/SYSTEM/1 to move: 9
/my-tmp/SYSTEM/2 to move: 100
/my-tmp/SYSTEM/3 to move: 0
/my-tmp/SYSTEM/4 to move: 22
```

Kind regards /K

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue outside of Firebase? I would be great if you posted a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Can you add some `console.log` statements (and their output) to the code to show what is going wrong (so that one of them prints too early)?

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen! I think I might have forgotten to await in "moveStuff()". :D Have added more code and logout to clarify. /K

Comment: Ah, I had added my console.log in the wrong places and did not async/await "moveStuff" - now it is working! /K

Comment: Good to hear! If you think others may make the same mistake, it might be worth posting a self-answer with the working code and an explanation of the fix. Otherwise, I'll vote to close this as a "typo".

Comment: Thank you Frank, I agreee! Have added an answer. Kind regards /K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by clarifying the execution process with more console logs and implementation of async/await.

`moveStuff()`

```
moveStuff : async ({dbRoot, from, to}) => {
  let myPromises = []
  await dbRoot.child(from).once('value', (snaps)=>{
    console.log(`moveStuff from '${from}' --> '${to}'`)
    console.log(`${from} to move:`, snaps.numChildren())
    snaps.forEach((node)=>{
      const path = `${to}/${node.key}`
      const nodeData = node.val()
      myPromises.push(
        dbRoot.child(path).set(nodeData)
        .then((writeRes)=> {
          return dbRoot.child(from).remove()
        })
        .then((deleteRes)=>{
          return Promise.resolve(true)
        })
        .catch((e)=>{
          console.error('moveStuff error', e)
          return Promise.reject(e)
        })
      )
    })
  })
  return myPromises
}
```

Promise chain:

```
  return Promise.all(firstPromises)
  .then((firstResult) => {
    // Proceed move data from firstPromises to another location
    console.log('First finished')
    let movePromises = []
    movePromises = movePromises.concat(await myFunc.moveStuff({dbRoot, from:`${tmpPath}/1`, to:'one'}))
    movePromises = movePromises.concat(await myFunc.moveStuff({dbRoot, from:`${tmpPath}/2`, to:'two'}))
    movePromises = movePromises.concat(await myFunc.moveStuff({dbRoot, from:`${tmpPath}/3`, to:'three'}))
    movePromises = movePromises.concat(await myFunc.moveStuff({dbRoot, from:`${tmpPath}/4`, to:'four'}))
    return Promise.all(movePromises)
  }) 
  .then((moveResult) => {
    // Result from Promise.all(movePromises)
    console.log('Move finished')
    // Clean up
    return Promise.all(cleanPromises)
  })
  .then((cleanResult) => {
    console.log('Clean finished')
    // Result from Promise.all(cleanPromises)
    return Promise.resolve(true)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error('Error', err)
    // Clean up
    cleanPromises.push(myFunc.cleanup({dbRoot, path:tmpPath}))
    return Promise.all(cleanPromises)
    // return Promise.reject(err)
  })
```

My logout now shows

```
First finished
Move finished
Clean finished
Function execution took 3473 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
```